# Windows Management Framework 4.0 via GPO

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, framework

I'm planning to set up a PowerShell-Masterserver. In order to do that I want to make sure that every Computer and Server running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 has PowerShell 4.0 installed. To achieve that I have to install Windows Management Framework 4.0

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

My concern is, in my GP are not only Windows 7 PCs - there are also Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 PCs. If i deploy the Framework via GPO, what happens on the 8.1 and 10 machines? because in technet there is this remark:

```
WMF 4.0 can only be installed on the following OS.

    Windows 7 with Service Pack 1
    Windows Server 2008 R2with Service Pack 1
```

Same story in my server GP | most of the servers are Windows Server 2012 R2, only a few are 2008 R2. Am I creating a failure with this?

Comment: Just add a wmi filter to the GPO so that it only targets windows 7 PCs

Comment: ok, I didn't know you can do that. thank you. Is it even a good idea to install the framework? I just read this article and it says that installing the framework can really destroy your OS http://serverfault.com/questions/458759/should-i-install-windows-management-framework-3-0?rq=1

Comment: It can, just like anything else if you don't read the requirements. Go through the list and make sure they do/don't apply